# DayClick event alert in fullcalendar when compare dates

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

When a user clicks on a day slot in a month view in the Fullcalendar dayClick event I'd like to have an alert saying that this date is not available. There are dates on a Calendar that are blocked, for example 12/10/2012 - 12/14/2012.

I wrote this code, but since I'm a newbie, I need that somebody please help me to understand what is wrong here:

```
    dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
    var myDate=new Date();
    myDate.setFullYear(2012,11,10);

    var deadline=new Date();
    deadline.setFullYear(2012,11,14);

   if (myDate <= deadline)
   {
   alert("No reservations available");
   return false;
   }
```

The fullcalendar is integrated in a ASP.NET MVC app.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/100thGear/zBZrs/

You need to compare the `date` parameter that gets passed to the `dayClick` eventCallback to your deadlines.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Works just fine! Could you please advise how to colorize these "not available" days, if possible? Thank you again very much!